# SQLAlchemy Обновление нескольких полей у нескольких объектов одним запросом к базе данных

Tags: python, sql, postgresql, sqlalchemy, fastapi

У меня есть список объектов модели Category, у которых изменились поля name, parent_id и archive, и мне нужно обновить эти объекты в базе данных. Сейчас я делаю это циклом - получаю объект из базы по id, задаю новые значения полей и обновляю объект. Это не оптимальный вариант и хотелось бы узнать, как я могу сделать это одним запросом к базе данных?

```
def update(id: int, instance: Category) -> None:
        instance.id = id
        instance = session.merge(instance)
        session.commit()
        return instance

def update_categories(categorues_to_update: list[Category]):
    for category_to_update in categories_to_update:
        category = session.execute(select(Category).where(Category.id==category_to_update.id))
        category.name = category_to_update.name
        category.parent_id = category_to_update.parent_id
        category.archive = category_to_update.archive
        update(category.id, category)
```

Comment: В стандартном SQL запрос на обновление может обновить только одну таблицу. Некоторые СУБД имеют расширение, позволяющее обойти это ограничение. В частности, в PostgreSQL такое расширение есть, и обновление записей нескольких таблиц в одном запросе выполняется с использованием CTE. Правда, я сильно сомневаюсь, что такой запрос возможно отобразить на код sqlalchemy...

Comment: @Akina мне нужно обновить записи только в одной таблице, а не в нескольких. Просто записей несколько и у каждой несколько полей.

Comment: На уровне SQL есть варианты синтаксиса для обновления нескольких записей одним запросом, причём  как для значений-литералов, так и для использования результатов подзапроса. Но опять же, вряд ли это отображается в код фреймворка. Для него итерации - это как раз нормально. А сырой SQL, как я понимаю, тебе не подходит.

Comment: @Akina а какой самый оптимальный способ есть осуществить этот запрос в SQLAlchemy? Неужели мой через цикл и присваивание нового значения каждому полю?